# Can I use custom strings that aren't converted in DateTime::format()?

Tags: php

I would like to get som customized output/result of the `DateTime::format()` function. In my examples below I would like to add the non-converted text "week", "w", or similar before the week number:

```
<?php
    echo (new DateTime())->format("Y, wW") . "<br>";
    echo (new DateTime())->format("Y, \wW") . "<br>";
    echo (new DateTime())->format("Y, \w\kW") . "<br>";
    echo (new DateTime())->format("Y, \w\e\e\kW") . "<br>";
    echo (new DateTime())->format("Y, 'week'W") . "<br>";

   /* Output:
      2022, 246
      2022, w46
      2022, wk46  <-- \e results in hidden ESC characters
      2022, wk46  <-- \e results in hidden ESC characters
      2022, /2k46
   */
?>
```

The first output converts 'w' to weekday number. I try to escape the conversion in the following lines, but with different results.

So... Is there a way to add custom strings within the `DateTime::format()` function?

Comment: Manual on DateTime::format: _"You can prevent a recognized character in the format string from being expanded by escaping it with a preceding backslash. **If the character with a backslash is already a special sequence, you may need to also escape the backslash.**"_ - since you use double quotes, that part is true for `\e`, because that means an escape character.

Comment: You could try wrapping the strings in single quotes

Comment: Thanks... both comments helped. I obviously only read parts of the manual ;)

Comment: `echo (new DateTime())->format("Y, \\w\\e\\e\\kW") . "<br>";`This kind of code should work...?